# Unable to get anything other than 'Remote scan' when selecting from linked MySql server

Tags: sql-server-2012, linked-server, mysql-5.1, remote

I have a linked server in SQL Server 2012 (SP3) that points to a MySql 5.1.61 server on another machine.

Whatever I do, I don't seem to be able to get any `where` filtering to occur on the remote side.

I tried all possible combinations of the linked 'Server Options' (Collation Compatible, RPC, RPC Out, Use Remote Collation, Collation Name, Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions for PRC), I also tried different MySql connectors for ODBC (v5.1, v5.2) and tried to put (or omit) various `charset` clauses in the connection string.

There is only one table I'm interested in, I'm only doing `select`s, there are proper indices on that table for any query I might want to make, all queries execute instantly when run directly on the MySql machine, but all of them result in this execution plan in SQL Server:

[image]

The table contains millions of rows and it is extremely slow.

The only thing that works for me in this situation is [dynamic `openquery`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3378496/11683), but that needs to be in a stored procedure, and I would very much like to expose this functionality as a view.

If that matters, the MySql database charset is `latin1 (ISO 8859-1 West European)` and collation is `latin1_swedish_ci`.

What have I missed and how do I make it work?

Comment: If this was a SQL Server remote, I would say that the security context for the Linked Server connection did not have sufficient permission to analyse the query against the linked server to determine a good plan. Does the execution plan show an estimated row count for the Remote Scan?

Comment: @MisterMagoo Yes, I saw [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175129%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) too. Just for the sake of it, I made the linked server connect under a mysql account with all permissions assigned, that did not change anything. The row estimate is 10000, I assume this is a hardcoded guess figure.